# Prolog: ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Tags: prolog, clpfd, zebra-puzzle, instantiation-error

### The code at the end on my post is supposed to answer the following puzzle:

> Brown, Clark, Jones and Smith are 4 substantial citizens who serve
>   their community as achitect, banker, doctor and lawyer, though not
>   necessarily    respectively. Brown, who is more conservative than
>   Jones but more liberal than Smith, is a better golfer than the men who
>   are YOUNGER than he is and has a larger income than the men who are
>   OLDER than Clark.
>       The banker, who earns more than the architect, is neither the youngest nor the oldest.
>
> The doctor, who is a poorer golfer than the lawyer, is less
>   conservative than the architect.
>        As might be expected, the oldest man is the most conservative and has the largest income, and the youngest man is the best golfer.
>        What is each man's profession?

---

when I try to launch the code, I get the error:

```
ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

The code is:

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% We represent each "person" with a six-tuple of the form
%
% [ name , profession , age , income , politics , golf ranking ]
%
% where name is either brown, clark, jones, or smith
%       profession is either banker, lawyer, doctor, or architect
%       age is a range 1 .. 4, with 1 being the youngest and 4 the oldest
%       income is a range 1 .. 4, with 1 being the least and 4 the most
%       politics is a range 1 .. 4, with 1 being conservative, 4 liberal
%       golf ranking is a range 1 .. 4, 1 for the best rank, 4 for the worst
%

solutions(L) :- L = [ [brown, _, _, _, _, _], [clark, _, _, _, _, _],
                      [jones, _, _, _, _, _], [smith, _, _, _, _, _] ],
                clue1(L),
                clue2(L),
                clue3(L),
                clue4(L),
                constrained_profession(L),
                constrained_age(L),
                constrained_income(L),
                constrained_politics(L),
                constrained_golf_rank(L).

%
% clue #1
% brown, who is more conservateive than jones but
% more liberal than smith, is a better golfer than
% the men who are younger than he is and has a larger
% income than the men who are older than clark
%

clue1(L) :- member(P1,L), member(P2,L), member(P3,L),
            P1 = [brown, _, A1, _, L1, G1],
            P2 = [jones, _, _, _, L2, _],
            P3 = [smith, _, _, _, L3, _],
            liberaler( P2, P1 ),
            liberaler( P1, P3 ),
            not( clue1_helper_a(L) ),
            not( clue1_helper_b(L) ).

% for all men younger than brown he is a better golfer ===>
% it is not the case that there exists a man younger than brown
% such that brown is not a better golfer than him.
% The "is not the case" is taken care of in clue1.

clue1_helper_a(L) :- member(P1,L), P1 = [brown, _, A1, _, L1, G1],
                     member(PU,L), PU = [_, _, AU, _, _, GU],
                     younger(PU,P1),
                     not(golfier(P1, PU)).

% for all men older than clark, brown makes more money than they do ===>
% it is not the case that there exists a man older than clark such that
% brown does not make more money than him.
% The "is not the case" is taken care of in clue1.

clue1_helper_b(L) :- member(P1,L), P1 = [brown, _, _, _, _, _],
                     member(P2,L), P2 = [clark, _, _, _, _, _],
                     member(PU,L), PU = [_, _, _, _, _, _],
                     younger(P2,PU),
                     not(richer(P1, PU)).

%
% clue #2
% the banker, who earns more than the archiect, is
% neither the youngest nor the oldest
%

clue2(L) :- member(P1,L), member(P2,L),
            P1 = [_, banker, A1, I1, _, _],
            P2 = [_, architect, _, I2, _, _],
            richer(P1,P2),
            not( A1 = 1 ),
            not( A1 = 4 ).

%
% clue #3
% the doctor, who is a pooer golfer than the lawyer, is
% less conservative than the architect. 
%

clue3(L) :- member(P1, L), member(P2, L), member(P3,L),
            P1 = [_,doctor, _, _, L1, G1],
            P2 = [_,lawyer, _, _, _, G2],
            P3 = [_,architect, _, _, L3, _],
            golfier(P2,P1),
            liberaler(P1,P3).

%
% clue #4
% as might be expected, the oldest man is the most
% conservative and has the largest income, and the 
% youngest man is the best golfer.

clue4(L) :- member(P1,L), member(P2,L),
            P1 = [_, _, 4, 4, 1, _],
            P2 = [_, _, 1, _, _, 1].

%
% relations
%

younger(X,Y) :- X = [_, _, AX, _, _, _], Y = [_, _, AY, _, _, _], AX < AY.

liberaler(X,Y) :- X = [_, _, _, _, LX, _], Y = [_, _, _, _, LY, _], LX > LY.

golfier(X,Y) :- X = [_, _, _, _, _, GX], Y = [_, _, _, _, _, GY], GX < GY.

richer(X,Y) :- X = [_, _, _, IX, _, _], Y = [_, _, _, IY, _, _], IX > IY.

%
% constraints
%

constrained_profession(L) :-
    member(P1,L), member(P2,L), member(P3,L), member(P4,L),
    P1 = [_, banker, _, _, _, _],
    P2 = [_, lawyer, _, _, _, _],
    P3 = [_, doctor, _, _, _, _],
    P4 = [_, architect, _, _, _, _].

constrained_age(L) :-
    member(P1,L), member(P2,L), member(P3,L), member(P4,L),
    P1 = [_, _, 1, _, _, _],
    P2 = [_, _, 2, _, _, _],
    P3 = [_, _, 3, _, _, _],
    P4 = [_, _, 4, _, _, _].

constrained_income(L) :-
    member(P1,L), member(P2,L), member(P3,L), member(P4,L),
    P1 = [_, _, _, 1, _, _],
    P2 = [_, _, _, 2, _, _],
    P3 = [_, _, _, 3, _, _],
    P4 = [_, _, _, 4, _, _].

constrained_politics(L) :-
    member(P1,L), member(P2,L), member(P3,L), member(P4,L),
    P1 = [_, _, _, _, 1, _],
    P2 = [_, _, _, _, 2, _],
    P3 = [_, _, _, _, 3, _],
    P4 = [_, _, _, _, 4, _].

constrained_golf_rank(L) :-
    member(P1,L), member(P2,L), member(P3,L), member(P4,L),
    P1 = [_, _, _, _, _, 1],
    P2 = [_, _, _, _, _, 2],
    P3 = [_, _, _, _, _, 3],
    P4 = [_, _, _, _, _, 4].

% end


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: When `liberaler` is called for `jones` and `brown` their politics is still a free variable so I get this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in predicate `(>)/2` is a so-called **moded** predicate. This means that you can only use it in very specific circumstances. It is not a true relation that you can use in all directions.

To reason more generally over integers, use your Prolog system's **CLP(FD) constraints** *instead*.

For example, in GNU Prolog, it suffices to simply **replace `(>)/2` by `(#>)/2`** to reason over integers more declaratively.

In other Prolog systems, you may currently need to import a dedicated library. For example, in SICStus Prolog, you need to add the directive:

> ```
> :- use_module(library(clpfd)).
> ```

to your program.

If you do this, and then use the following slightly modified definitions of your predicates:

```
younger(X,Y) :- X = [_, _, AX, _, _, _], Y = [_, _, AY, _, _, _], AX #< AY.

liberaler(X,Y) :- X = [_, _, _, _, LX, _], Y = [_, _, _, _, LY, _], LX #> LY.

golfier(X,Y) :- X = [_, _, _, _, _, GX], Y = [_, _, _, _, _, GY], GX #< GY.

richer(X,Y) :- X = [_, _, _, IX, _, _], Y = [_, _, _, IY, _, _], IX #> IY.
```

The the example query runs *without errors*:

```
?- solutions(L).
false.
```

However, as you see, your formulation is currently **too specific**: Not a single solution is found.

Consider filing a separate question to see how you can debug such issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mat! I will post a separate question and hope you can help me there.

Comment: Yes, please do. Thank you!